# Huawei Map Kit - Certificates

Tags: dictionary, certificate, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

Summary of our problem:
We released last week our app bundle in the Huawei AppGallery.
We used the Huawei Map Kit in order to integrate Maps. However, there seems to be a problem with map kit.

We receive the error messages:
V/HmsMapKit_MapDataVersionClient_15: build request with apiKey
D/HmsMapKit_AuthenticateClient_86: response code : 401
E/HmsMapKit_TileCache_38: startUrlRequest Identity fail, do not has permission get tile. authResult :010002

What we have done so far:

- Enable mapkit in AppGallery connect
- Add sha256 fingerprints of the signed bundle to the app in AppGallery conncet
- Build the app with agconnect-services.json
- Initializing mapkit with the api key setup on the huawei developer page
- Encode the API key as below: URLEncoder.encode("", "utf-8")
- Tested the rc before uploading where it worked perfectly fine

As we are having troubles in identifying the cause for our problem, it would be very helpful to get further advice.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you are.using signing by AppGallery.

If so, you have to add one more SHA-256 to project settings, which you can get from application singing settings in console

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/faq-0000001050166999-V5#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001050166999__section9358141913329?ha_source=hms1),It's most likely caused by the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When localy building apk works but store submitted apk does not work, it is most likely the signing issue.

And for App bundle signing, there are 2 ways.

AppGallery Connect generates a new [signature key](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-introduction-0000001051379577#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001051379577__p526252616329) for your new app

App Signing allows you to upload your own [signature key](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-introduction-0000001051379577#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001051379577__p526252616329)

NOTE

Once a signature key is generated in AppGallery Connect or uploaded by you, it cannot be modified.

so depends on the approach, you might already have a signature key that is fixed already.

and it seems in this case you have your own signature key.

when we need to use upload key to sign apk before submit to AppGallery, do not use signature key to sign for upload apk, in this case, also upload key certificate and upload key to AppGallery.

need to make sure signature key certificate and upload key certificate are correct if used.